# No X-AppEngine-Region in AppEngine App headers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-app-engine, express

I am trying to get the Region an Country in the request. I thought it was possible to get the `X-AppEngine-Region` and `X-AppEngine-Country` headers in every request to AppEngine, but they are missing. Sometimes the headers are provisional and sometimes they're like this (only listing keys):

```
alt-svc 
content-length 
content-type 
date 
etag 
server 
status 
via 
x-powered-by
```

Here is my code. What do I have to do to get the Region and Country as well?

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send(req.headers['X-AppEngine-Region'] || '');
});

app.post('/ping', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send(req.headers['X-AppEngine-Region'] || '');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These headers aren't available in nodejs env, there are available with Go, Java, PHP with standard env (not flexible).

More: 
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/how-requests-are-handled

Comment: Thanks @kcp I'll try that.

Comment: Would you happen to know how to change from flex to standard env? I switched to a Java app but am still not getting the headers.